# react - setState find object item then assign

Tags: object, reactjs, assign, setstate

i have object in state -

```
this.state = {
  states: {
    na: 0, s1a: 0, s2a: 0, s3a: 0, s4a: 0, l1a: 0, l2a: 0, l3a: 0, t1a: 0, t2a: 0, t3a: 0,
    nb: 0, s1b: 0, s2b: 0, s3b: 0, s4b: 0, l1b: 0, l2b: 0, l3b: 0, t1b: 0, t2b: 0, t3b: 0
  },
```

and i want to change value of some key i my function -

```
onInputUpdated(id){
var array = {};
let char = id.slice(-1);

switch(char){
  case 'a':
    array[id] = this.getY(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[id].refs.inp).value);
    break;

  case 'b':
    array[id] = this.getX(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[id].refs.inp).value);
    break;
}

this.setState({
  states: { id : array[id]}
});
```

but there is no id, id represents string 'na' or others... so how i can do it? any tips pls? btw onIputUpdated(id) is callBack from children..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cant update nested states directly. You will to have to update the whole "states" object. Something like this

`let oldStates = this.state.states;
oldStates[id] = array[id];
this.setState({
    states: {
       ...oldStates
    }
});`